# Why are vacuum tubes in vacuum and how high vacuum has to be so that electrons can flow through it freely?

Tags: electrons, vacuum

As in the title, I'm curious about electron movement through vacuum, how high vacuum has to be to make vacuum tubes work and how to calculate friction caused by air when electrons are moving through it?

Comment: Possibly related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/657174/101743

Comment: The RCA tube manual is considered the 'tube bible' for most practical purposes.  Check if your answer is in here:   http://www.tubebooks.org/tubedata/rc30.pdf